# Script error when Transform PO to Item Receipt Error

Tags: javascript, transform, netsuite, suitescript, receipt

I'm new to suitescript, I've got a schedule script to Transform a PO to Item Receipt. Which needs to create a record on Subrecord on inventorydetail sub record, I get "USER_ERROR","message":"The total inventory detail quantity must be 1."  - Not sure what I have done wrong. If i use the same code for a non stock and remove the sub record insert line and coding it works

```
   var csvPOId = 73586;
        var csvPOLocationId = 1;
        var csvPOQty = 1;
        var csvBinId = '';
        var csvSerialLot = '';
        var csvInvQty = 1;
        //

        try {
            var itemReceiptRec = record.transform({
                fromType: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER,
                fromId: csvPOId,
                toType: record.Type.ITEM_RECEIPT,
                isDynamic: false
            });
        } catch (e) {
            log.error({
                title: e.name,
                details: e.message
            });
        }


        // Get count - Sublist Lines
        var count = itemReceiptRec.getLineCount({
            sublistId: 'item'
        });

        for (var i=0; i < count; i++) {

            // Item Sub List - Mark as Received
            var itemReceived = itemReceiptRec.getSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'itemreceive',
                line: i
            });

            // Location
            itemReceiptRec.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'location',
                value: csvPOLocationId, // '11 - Central Main Warehouse',
                line: i
            });
            // Quantity

            itemReceiptRec.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'quantity',
                value: csvPOQty,
                line: i
            });

            // Inventory Detail Sub Record [inventorydetail]

            var subrec = itemReceiptRec.getSublistSubrecord({
                sublistId: 'item',
                line: i,
                fieldId: 'inventorydetail'
            });
            subrec.insertLine({
                sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                line: 0
            });
            // // Quantity - Mandatory
            subrec.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
                fieldId: 'quantity',
                line: 0,
                value: csvInvQty
            });
        var itemRecID = itemReceiptRec.save({
            enableSourceing: true
        });

        log.debug({
            title: 'New Item Receipt Record',
            details: 'Internal ID ' + itemRecID
        });
```

Comment: I've dropped the } for the For statement when copying and pasting logic. } goes just before the itemReceiptRec.save function.

Comment: FYI - I'm trying to receipt 3 Inventory Item lines from the PO, all have a quantity of 1

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with your way of setting the values.

Follow this logic (haven't included the subrecord logic)-

```
for(var j=0; j<count; j++) {

   itemReceiptRec.selectLine({
      sublistId: 'item',
      line: j
   )};

   var itemReceived = itemReceiptRec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'item',
                fieldId: 'itemreceive',
                line: j
   });

   // Location
   itemReceiptRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'location',
        value: csvPOLocationId, // '11 - Central Main Warehouse',
   });

   // Quantity
   itemReceiptRec.setSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'quantity',
        value: csvPOQty,
   });

   //Similarly add subrecord code logic
   //Notice I haven't used 'line' while setting sublist value
 
   itemReceiptRec.commitLine({
      sublistId: 'item'
   });
}

itemReceiptRec.save();
```

Also change 'isDynamic' from false to true.

```
var itemReceiptRec = record.transform({
                fromType: record.Type.PURCHASE_ORDER,
                fromId: csvPOId,
                toType: record.Type.ITEM_RECEIPT,
                isDynamic: true
});
```

Let me know for any issues in comments below

Comment: Hi, I tried isDynamic: true and it gives me an error. Also you have suggested itemReceiptRec.setCurrentSublistValue, but this is not a Client Script, it's a scheduled script which runs on the server.

Comment: @Renzo setCurrentSublistValue works on server side scripts. I myself have used it in Map Reduce and UserEvents. Give it a try! Might provide you some breakthrough

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm a newbie always grateful for advice and tips.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting other things like `binnumber` or `issueinventorynumber`. Unless the item you are receiving needs to go to a bin or has an inbound serial or lot number then you likely don't need to do anything with the `inventoryassignment` sublist.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, i will try remove the subRecord logic

Comment: Thank you for your advice, It worked, by removing the logic to subRecord.

Comment: @Renzo if this answer worked for you, then you need to mark it as the right answer.